# Rapi.dll / OpenNETCF slow issues on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile, windows-vista, opennetcf, rapi

I am referencing OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication (Rapi.dll) in my project and have the following problem:

When I for ex. "private RAPI mobjRapi = new RAPI();"...
it takes about 5 minutes to execute that statement. I am basically trying to copy a file from a mobile device

An additional issue which might be related is that when I click "Windows Mobile Device Center" in control panel. I get the message "Windows Mobile Device Center is starting up" with the splash screen and then just disappear without opening the application.

More about my setup:

- Windows Vista 64-bit
- Visual Studio 2005 (C#)
- Windows Mobile Device Center 6.1 Recently installed
- Psion Workabout PRO mobile product scanner connected with USB (the device is accessable from My Computer)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you setup a device partnership in Windows Mobile Device Center? Please make sure you do, because otherwise it can cause problems trying to debug from Visual Studio.

You can check under Control Panel -> Sync Center if there already is a partnership for your device. If not, please attach the device to the USB port and when the WMDC screen comes up, go through the option of setting up a partnership. After this the WMDC screen should indicate that the device is connected and you're ready to go.

Comment: yes thank you that was indeed the problem I found yesterday.  

The = new RAPI() hangs when IdccMan.Advice() is called and there is not partnership with WDMC and the mobile device.

The fact that I couldn't get WDMC running was because of what I believed was issues with WDMC and Vista 64-bit.  Un-installing WDMC and the re-install with the WDMC drivers upgrade for Vista 64 enabled me to open the app and set up a partnership